# Median windows in C

Tags: c

I wrote a code to find [median filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870349/two-dimensional-array-median-filtering) (median window). But, I can't make scannig to every number. What can I use instead of `size` in the for loops. When I use size it ensures just `5` Also, what about boundries ? What can I do for boundries ? Thank you for all appreciated answers. (I've opened new topic because users said that every topic is based on one question.If I did mistake,please delete the question, I will suffix the current question)

```
    <size of array>
    <size filter> 
    <data>
    8
    3
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 5 0 0 6 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0
    0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0
    0 0 0 5 6 0 0 0
    0 0 8 5 5 0 0 0
    0 0 0 7 0 0 9 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

    Output:
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0
    0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int median(int a[100],int n);


int main()
{
    int a[100][100];
    int temp[100];
    int i,j,k,count=0;
    int sizefilter;
    int sizearray;

    scanf("%d", &sizearray);
    scanf("%d", &sizefilter);

    for(i = 0; i < sizearray; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < sizearray; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

    for(k = 0; k < sizearray; k++)
        for(i = 0; i < sizefilter; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < sizefilter; j++)
            {
                temp[count] = a[i][j];
                count++;
                a[i][j] = median(temp, count);
            }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < sizearray; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < sizearray; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);

            if(j == sizearray-1)
                printf("\n");
        }

    return 0;
}

int median(int a[100],int n)
{
    int i,j,t;
    int result;
    /* Sorting begins */
    for (i = 1 ; i <= n-1 ; i++)
    {     /* Trip-i begins  */
        for (j = 1 ; j <= n-i ; j++)
        {
             if (a[j] <= a[j+1])
             { /* Interchanging values */

                 t = a[j];
                 a[j] = a[j+1];
                 a[j+1] = t;
             }
             else continue ;
         }
    } /* sorting ends */

    /* calculation of median  */
    if ( n % 2 == 0)
        return  result = (a[n/2] + a[n/2+1])/2 ;
    else
        return result = a[n/2 + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some logical errors in your code:

- When you filter, you need four nested loops: The outer two iterate over columns and rows of the matrix, the inner two iterate over columns and rows of the filter area. (That shouldn't be news to you; you have already been told that in an answer to your previous question.)
- The constraints of the filter area are simple: The left and top indices must not fall below zero and the right and bottom indicies must be smaller than `sizearray`. If they are not, adjust them.
- You need two arrays, the original array `a` and a second array that contains the filtered values. You cannot filter in-place, because if you look upwards and to the left, you'll see only filtered values, whereas your filter should always look at the original values.
- Your wrong filtering loops apart: You never reset `count`, which you should reset, of course, for every median value you calculate. You also calculate the median in the inner loop, which is too often. A solution to this is to make `count` local to the loop that accumulates filter values and determines the median.
- Your sorting has index errors. Instead of comparing `i` with `i + 1`,  compare with ´i - 1`. Your indices start from 1, so`i - 1` will always yield a valid index.
- You buble-sort the array, which is fine for small arrays, but slow in general. The `<stdlib.h>` has `qsort`, which may be useful to you for general sorting.
- Your median indices are also off by one towards the right.

There are also some stylistic issues:

- Please make a habit of using braces for code blocks for `for`, `while` and `if`. Only very trivial code blocks in the innermost scope can be written without braces. In your case, a lot has to be done "between"  the loops, and having braces there makes it easy to add stuff.
- Yor variable `result` in `median` is superfluous. You assign it and then immediately lose the variable itself, because you return. Just returning is enough.

Below is a version of your code that gives the desired output:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int median(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
        for (j = 1 ; j < n ; j++) {
             if (a[j] < a[j - 1]) {
                 int t = a[j];
                 a[j] = a[j - 1];
                 a[j - 1] = t;
             }
         }
    }

    if (n % 2) return a[n / 2];
    return (a[n / 2 - 1] + a[n / 2]) / 2 ;        
}

int main()
{
    int a[100][100];
    int b[100][100];
    int temp[100];
    int i, j, ii, jj;
    int sizefilter;
    int sizearray;

    scanf("%d", &sizearray);
    scanf("%d", &sizefilter);

    for(i = 0; i < sizearray; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < sizearray; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizearray; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < sizearray; j++) {
            int imin = max(0, i - sizefilter / 2);
            int imax = min(sizearray, i + sizefilter / 2 + 1);
            int jmin = max(0, j - sizefilter / 2);
            int jmax = min(sizearray, j + sizefilter / 2 + 1);
            int count = 0;

            for (ii = imin; ii < imax; ii++) {
                for (jj = jmin; jj < jmax; jj++) {
                    temp[count] = a[ii][jj];
                    count++;
                }
            }

            b[i][j] = median(temp, count);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizearray; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < sizearray; j++) {
            printf("%3d", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how can I thank you ? Are you instructor in a university ? Thank you so much.